# Merge tag [meanio] into [mean.io]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The tags [meanio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meanio) and [mean.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean.io) are being used for the same purpose. As [mean.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean.io) has 200 questions (vs 4) and a more substantial tag wiki, I recommend that it be kept as the main tag and that [meanio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meanio) be merged into it.

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean.io